# Подскажите, нужна ли здесь запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Все, чего хочет Лидия(,) – это вычеркнуть из памяти Скотта.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире в вашем случае нужно.

> Тире ставится после запятой, закрывающей придаточную часть, при «переломе» конструкции, перед словом это и т. д.:

**Ср.: Единственное, что мне здесь нравится, — это старый тенистый парк;**

См.: [Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении.Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь.Д.Э.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144)

Comment: Про тире вопросов нет, суть в запятой)) Спасибо!

Comment: В этом случае ставится запятая и тире.

Comment: Я добавил ссылку.

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли! Искала все утро ответ... Еще раз благодарю, Вы мой герой))

Comment: И мой тоже. :) Совсем забыл, что такое возможно. " И Розенталя не читал..."